# Ad hoc app hangs at launch, "has active assertions but is being debugged"

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

The app works just fine when I run it in debug mode on my devices or the simulator. But when I build it for ad-hoc distribution, the app launches but stays stuck on the initial launch screen. When I pull up the console, it says the app "has active assertions but is being debugged". Has anyone ever encountered this before? A Google search of this phrase brings up zero results...

I have successfully built it for ad-hoc previously, so I'm not sure what's going on here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure what is causing this, but quitting and relaunching Xcode seems to fix the problem. It's happened more than once now and relaunching has always fixed it.